# How to revert back several blocks in Bitcoin Core without re-syncing from scratch

Tags: bitcoin-core

My node was running on a computer that I accidentally unplugged and it died. When trying to restart Core now it is not working, presumably because the computer dying forced Core to exit non-gracefully.

I'm wondering if there's a way for me to "rewind" back to a state before my computer crashed, so I don't have to resync the entire chain from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

If the state is corrupt, there's no operation that will be able to restore it. A `reindex` will re-sync using the block files already on disk without having to re-download them where possible, but there's no escaping needing to do the CPU expensive operation of synchronization.